# How to disable compression with Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0

Tags: android, gradle

I've recently updated my project to use the Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0. I don't use Android Studio, though, but everything is done from the command line. When I say

```
./gradlew build
```

I get the following errors:

```
Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor570.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore
```

(and lots of consecutive errors)

After some experimenting I've found out that these errors are caused by the following lines in my `build.gradle`:

```
aaptOptions {
    noCompress ''
}
```

When removing these lines, it works just fine and there are no more errors. So how do I need to adapt these lines in order to work with the Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0? I absolutely need to disable compression for all files inside the APK so I need some way to make this work with the Gradle Plugin 3.0.0.

Comment: Hmmm... the docs still say that `noCompres ''` should work. You might try [temporarily disabling AAPT2](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0.html): "If you are experiencing issues while using AAPT2, you can disable it by setting android.enableAapt2=false in your gradle.properties file and restarting the Gradle daemon by running ./gradlew --stop from the command line."

Comment: I don't see that specific problem reported [in the issue tracker when searching on `noCompress`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=noCompress). If you can create a reproducible test case, I encourage you to file an issue.

Comment: Alright, done that.